# Angular2 bind service data with model var

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angularjs-bindings

I have a class called test with property inside is data. How can I bind `home.showVar` with `test.data` so when test.data is updated, home.showVar gets updated too (I want to display list to user)

Basically I want to have service called test, which triggers api call, which then returns data and merge with existing data and then show to user. I'm new to angular2 and typescript. so I'm not sure how to merge http data with existing data and make it bind with different pages.

```
export class test {
    public data = 'yes';
    constructor() { }
}

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class Home {
    showVar;
    constructor(test: test) {
        this.showVar = test.data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bascially you need to create one function in the test class that return something or response. then in your class use that class method to get updated data. then assign to the `showVar` variable. hope it will help you.

```
export class test {
    public data = 'yes';
    constructor() { }
     demo(){
        return this.data;
      }
}

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class Home {
    showVar;
    constructor(private test: test) {
       this.test.demo(res=>{
          res= this.showVar;
       });
    }
}
```

Post more code this may clear your problem more. just for example i have posting one more example hope this may clear more using API call here is example:

here is my component file code just like your `home` component code:

```
API_call() {
    let url_getApi = 'Path or URl here...'

    this.APIService.getData(url_getApi)
        .subscribe(res=> {
            if (res) {
                this.showVar= res;
                console.log(res, "Data from API call");
            }
        });
}
```

now here is service file `(APIService.ts)` code i.r your test class code may look like:

```
getData(url) {
   return this.http.request(new Request(url, or RequestOptions as per need)
    .map(res => {
           return res.json();
        });
}
```

Comment: would this be connected all the time? Like if I update test.data, would home.showVar get updated automatically?

Comment: No i don't think so this will only updated when you call the method/function of your service file.

Comment: I get error on `this.test.demo(res=....) Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

Comment: do you provide some parameters along with method call for `this.test.demo` ? read my second example for help this may clear your problem else post your code or give me a plnkr ill help you.

Comment: @PardeenJain I need continuous bind with `test.demo` or with `test.data` as api gets updated or we decide to use existing data, since its not changed.

Comment: yes, you can continuous bind with `test.demo` whenever your api gets updated call this method again by this way your your `home.showVar` will get update every time.

Comment: I can do second example one, but I want to bind test class property, so whenever it updates, it should update all the pages of the application and not just current one (doing it for mobile app)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103405/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-basit).